# Google Chrome autoplays my embedded sound

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

Is there any way to disable this? I want to use jQuery to play the sound. I chose to use < embed >, because it doesn't require Flash and it works on all browsers/ platforms:

```
<embed src="sounds/button-9.mp3" autostart="false" width=0 height=0 id="newMsgSound" enablejavascript="true">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)? It uses JQuery at backend, and it supports both HTML5 and Flash. So, if your users are using IE, which doesn't have HTML5 support, jPlayer will automatically use Flash. If the device doesn't support Flash (say, iPhone, iPad), jPlayer will automatically use HTML5... everything is seamless to you as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, worked for me

1.- For NO autoplay

```
    <video controls name='media'>
        <source src="audios/myAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </video>
```

2.- For autoplay

```
    <video controls autoplay name='media'>
        <source src="audios/myAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </video>
```